# Intento insertar una columna en una tabla en VBA y me sale error 1004

Tags: base-de-datos, excel, formularios, vba

No se que pasa aquí dejo un link a drive con el excel.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Yi4vL8QxVpNS2hdA3sCBdASnmEjrdJS/view?usp=sharing
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que hace el botón supuestamente es agarrar los datos introducidos en el form y enviarlo a una hoja de excel pero no me deja insertar nuevas filas para introducir mas de una tanda de datos.
Me ayudarían por favor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad no es necesario insertar filas, tampoco hace falta mostrar y ocultar la hoja, puede estar oculta y aun así hacer los registros.

Puedes agregar una variable para obtener la siguiente fila vacía en la hoja, es importante destacar que la siguiente fila vacía se obtiene de diferente manera si se esta trabajando con una tabla excel que si se trabaja con un rango excel regular, esto se explica en el código siguiente que puede ayudar.

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim nombre As String
    Dim fecha As String
    Dim tarea As String
    Dim informe As String
    Dim sFila As Long
    
    'usar esta linea solo si se maneja rango normal de excel (no tabla)
    'sFila = Hoja6.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    'usar esta linea solo si se trabaja con tabla excel ( no rango )
    sFila = Hoja6.ListObjects("Tabla3").Range.Columns(1).Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
        
    nombre = TextBox1.Text
    fecha = TextBox2.Text
    tarea = TextBox3.Text
    informe = TextBox4.Text
    If (nombre <> "" And fecha <> "" And tarea <> "" And informe <> "") Then
        Hoja6.Range("A" & sFila).Value = nombre
        Hoja6.Range("B" & sFila).Value = fecha
        Hoja6.Range("C" & sFila).Value = tarea
        Hoja6.Range("D" & sFila).Value = informe
        TextBox1.Value = ""
        TextBox2.Value = ""
        TextBox3.Value = ""
        TextBox4.Value = ""
        MsgBox "Informe subido correctamente"
        Else
        MsgBox "Por favor complete los campos"
    End If
            
End Sub
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias ;)